# Can I qualify for program that has different requirements if you are from a different country than the other

Tags: graduate-admissions, university, degree, international-students

I was planning on going overseas for my higher education.
However when I went to look for the academic requirements needed for the degree I was concerned when I found out that the qualifications that were needed differed from country to country.

I was wondering if I could qualify for program that had different requirements which I have completed within my host country and get in the program even though the requirements for my country are completely opposite and it would take me time to complete those qualifications.

Answer (score 4):

That depends a lot on the program in question and I would advise you to contact them, as there is no general answer for that.

Just as a small remark: Usually, the requirements aren't that different. It's just that school/universities are different in different countries, so they might say "if you are from here, it is enough that you passed our Bachelor of XXX", while if you come from somewhere else (where this Bachelor might not exist in this form), you should have done this, that and that.
So if you think that you have fulfilled the requirements, just not in the exact way they stated it (because your classes had other names but the same content, for example), then you might have a good chance in getting in. But once again, this is for the person in charge of admissions to decide, so just contact him/her and ask.